# Sidecar vs Middleware

Tags: node.js, express, microservices, architectural-patterns

I'm building a microservice using express and need to some operations (say logging) on each request. I found that sidecar is useful pattern for this, but the same functionality can be achieved with express middleware. Is there any scenario where it would be recommended to use sidecar over using middleware?

Comment: A pretty good article on the considerations involved in the sidecar pattern: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/sidecar.  It really depends upon the specifics of the situation.  Sometimes the process or component isolation is beneficial, sometimes it's just extra overhead and complication that doesn't really buy you anything.  Which way the scales tip depend on the particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

One main advantage of using a sidecar is that you decouple your business-logic code from the logging-code (which is usually a 3rd-party library). This is an advantage because if the 3rd party inserts a bug which crashes the code, it won't affect the execution of your code (other than not logging).

The downside is that a sidecar, as any additional external process, requires an overhead of resources CPU, memory, disk and etc.

Comment: my understanding is that all requests go through sidecar and if library crashes sidecar it will crash the service anyway

Comment: if the sidecar crashes, the logging requests that your service will send to the sidecar will return an error, and since logging requests (should) be non-blocking - your service will continue running without a change.